# Error running catkin_make with tf2_geometry_msgs

Tags: ros, catkin-make, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running catkin make i get this error

" CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tf2_geometry_msgs"
with any of the following names:

```
tf2_geometry_msgsConfig.cmake
tf2_geometry_msgs-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "tf2_geometry_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "tf2_geometry_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "tf2_geometry_msgs" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed."

I downloaded the geometry2 package from github and added it to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH but that didn't work, so i grepped the package and nowhere in there do any files contain either of:

tf2_geometry_msgsConfig.cmake

tf2_geometry_msgs-config.cmake

If i can download one of these files and put its path in my CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH i think it should work, but if the geometry2 ros package doesn't contain these files, where can i find them?  I really need the package that requires these files so it's crucial that i find a way to build the workspace.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267495/error-running-catkin_make-with-tf2_geometry_msgs/) by [Ryan_F](https://answers.ros.org/users/31057/ryan_f/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Cmake config files are generated when you compile tf2_geometry_msgs. You either need it in your workspace or have it built and installed into an underlying workspace. Or you need to be building on top of the binary installed versions.

Please see the ROS tutorials for setting up your ROS environment: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan_F](https://answers.ros.org/users/31057/ryan_f/) on 2017-07-27**:
Thanks! This works

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-04-08**:
Is there any chance you could provide more information?